# Does std::variant provide functionality similar to boost::variant<>::types?

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-variant, boost-mpl, std-variant

`boost::variant` exposes its list of variant types via `boost::variant<>::types`, which can be conveniently used with `boost::mpl::for_each`. `std::variant` is missing such a member.

I see `std::variant_alternative` is provided. Can this be used to produce a type list that `boost::mpl::for_each` can ingest? Or does it enable a different iteration strategy?

Comment: What's the actual question? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% familiar with Boost.MPL, but this should do what you're looking for:

```
template <class Variant>
struct mpl_types_impl;

template <class... Ts>
struct mpl_types_impl<std::variant<Ts...>> {
    using type = boost::mpl::vector<Ts...>;
};

template <class Variant>
using mpl_types = typename mpl_types_impl<Variant>::type;
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0aYgTemKwhZbjwRY)

Comment: `std::tuple` -> `std::variant` to address the question?

Comment: @R2RT yep, seems like a good idea innit. *Sigh* - Edit: done, now for caffeinating that struggling brain.